# Deriving the maximum likelihood estimates for a multivariate Gaussian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am new to Mathematica and wonder if anyone can give me skeleton of a solution to a simple problem that I will then modify for my purposes as so far I have not managed to properly grasp the syntax.

The test case is simply deriving the closed form estimates of the sample mean vector and the variance co-variance matrix for a multivariate normal distribution. It would be nice to do so for an arbitrary number of variables $k$, with sample size $n$.

Note that $\mathbf{\mu}$ is the sample mean vector of length $k$, and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the $k$ by $k$ variance-covariance matrix.

Aim:

From PDF:

$f_{\mathbf{x}}(x_1,...,x_k)=2\pi^{-k/2}|\mathbf{\Sigma}|^{-1/2}\text{exp}\left ( -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\mu})\right )$

i) define likelihood function:

$L(\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma}|\mathbf{x}^{(i)})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}2\pi^{-k/2}|\mathbf{\Sigma}|^{-1/2}\text{exp}\left ( -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})\right )$

ii) define log-likelihood function:

$l(\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma}|\mathbf{x}^{(i)})=-\frac{nk}{2} \text{ln}\left (2\pi \right ) - \frac{n}{2}\text{ln}|\mathbf{\Sigma}| - \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})$

iii) Compute partial derivatives of $l$ w.r.t $\mathbf{\mu}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$. On paper the derivative w.r.t. the matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$ is performed by first substituting $(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})$ with the trace $tr\left [(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})^T(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\right ]$, and then noting that

- $\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}}tr\left [(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\right ]=(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\mathbf{\mu})^T$

iv) find maxima (well, stationary points at this stage) by setting both partial derivatives to zero and solve for the respective parameters giving:

$\hat{\mathbf{\mu}}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{\Sigma}}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\hat{\mathbf{\mu}})(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}-\hat{\mathbf{\mu}})^T$

If someone could guide me through the process in a Mathematica script I would be very grateful! Please note, I'm not a mathematician but I write quite a lot of code and while I can follow the derivation above, I would not have known to use the matrix-for-trace substitution.

Thanks,

J

Comment: You've already done it by hand though. _Mathematica_ isn't suited to handling matrices when you don't have a concrete dimension. I mean it's possible, but it's a lot of work. You can get the log-likelihood like this `observations = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {x5, y5}};
loglk = LogLikelihood[
   MultinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, {{s11, s12}, {s21, s22}}], 
   observations];`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I would like to modify the density function and apply the same procedure, I am using the multivariate normal as a standard case. Computing the log-likelihood for a given density function is relatively straight forward, but is there a way to perform step iv) above in Mathematica without declaring the dimensionality of the data?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, no.